# Three.js 3D models are not looking well and clean

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on 3D Modelling using Thrre.js , and have to display neat and clean product after reading a .DAE file  but my product display is not well clean and good . Can anybody please help me , i have also given the light sources but still product shown are very dull .[Actual product to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlA0D.png)

[My product image render screen shot , no leather is shown in product and also very dull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cxT6.png)

I am trying following Code :

```
<script>
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, light;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    document.body.style.cssText = 'margin: 0; overflow: hidden' ;
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: 1, antialias: true, clearColor: 0xffffff }  );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 50000 );
    camera.position.set( 100, 100, 100 );
    //camera.position.set(-15, 10, 15);
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    scene.add(camera);

    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 10);
    light.position.set(100,100, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(10, 10, 10).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    var pointlight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    pointlight.position.set(50, 100, 50)
    camera.add(pointlight);
    scene.add(pointlight);
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(10,10,10);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    var pointHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointlight, 0.1);
    scene.add(pointHelper);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0x333333, color: 0x888888, opacity: 0.000001, transparent: true } );
   // material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.name = 'basic template mesh';
    mesh.visible = false;
    scene.add( mesh );

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    controls.update();
}``
```

Through this code , i got the very dull product. 
Can Anyone Please help me to sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong material. The MeshLambertMaterial is used for diffuse surfaces, those that do not have specular highlights (paper, raw wood, cloth). You need to use the MeshPhongMaterial which allows the specular highlights (white spots) in the chair.

In your model, you have two types of surface: leather and wood. Even though both of them have specular highlights, their shininess are different. You will have to define separate materials for both surfaces. But, since I see you have a single object, this can be difficult. You can define a single MeshPhongMaterial for both surfaces, but you will have to try several values in the parameters to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks sosegon for reply , i will  follow your suggestions and get back tou you . Thanks anyways !!

Comment: Hi sosegen , i have applied MeshPhongMaterial as you suggested and tried the different patterns  but it still not working.


material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ ambient: 0x333333, color: 0x888888, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30, opacity: 0.000001, transparent: true });


Can you please suggest and put any relavant code .